# Transfer function in a 6th order Butterworth Filter

Tags: high-pass-filter, butterworth

> Design the next High-Pass Butterworth filter:
>
> - 3db attenuation at 2000Hz
> - 80db minimum attenuation at  in 400Hz

i know that 2000hz is my 3db cutoff frequency and 400hz my sampling frequency. Therefore, using the Butterworth curves: $$\Omega= 2000/400=5 \Rightarrow N=6$$

Using Butterworth coordenates i obtain:

[image]

I have three questions: how do I get the transfer function with the three poles (I don't have mathematical background in this, but i dont need a deep demostration), after that, how do I get the values of the resistors and capacitors from this transfer function?

I supposed to use infinite gain and multiple feedback configuration, so the filter should look like this:

[image]

I just need an implicit guide to the exercise, but if you can develop it, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Why do you mention sampling frequency? Surely this is a linear analogue question you are asking?